# Cambio de Password GAM

Tags: genexus

**GX17u2**
**java**

Necesito que el usuario pueda cambiar su clave cuando quiera. Para eso, tengo un WebPanel **CambioClave**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el envento **Start** tengo:

`&UserName = GamUser.GetName()`

Luego en **Confirmar**:

```
Event Enter 
    &User = GAMRepository.GetUserToChangePassword()
    //&GAMSession= GAMSession.Get(&Errors)  
    //&User=&GAMSession.User    
    If &UserPasswordNew = &UserPasswordNewConf 
        &isOK=&User.ChangeYourPassword(&UserPassword, &UserPasswordNew, &Errors)
        for &Error in &Errors
            GuardoLog.Call(&Error.Code.ToString().Trim()+"#"+&Error.Message.Trim())
        endfor
        //&isOK = GAMRepository.UpdateUserToChangePassword(&UserPassword, &UserPasswordNew, &Errors)
        //&isOK = &User.ChangePassword(&UserPassword,&UserPasswordNew,&Errors)
        If &isOK
            Msg("Se cambió la clave correctamente")
        Else
            &Errors = &User.GetErrors()
            Do 'DisplayMessages'
        Endif
    Else
        Msg("Las claves no coinciden")
    Endif
EndEvent
```

Luego que hago el cambio de clave y presiono confirmar, si bien me da **isOK=true** y luego envío la respuesta al usuario, me genera el siguiente log:

```
3#El tipo de autenticación no fue encontrado, por favor contacte al administrador.
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Obviamente no se pudo realizar el cambio de contraseña.

¿Me pueden dar una mano con esto? Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    &ChangeOK = GAMUser.ChangeYourPassword(&UserPassword, &UserPasswordNew, &Errors)
    If &ChangeOK
        commit
    Endif
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: tan solo faltaba el commit muchas gracias Luis!